# IP Canonicalization Test in codeigniter php

Tags: php

Opening an website with IP address redirecting some other page like http://60.60.92.125/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi like this .This is an example .

I have changed in htaccess file but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^60\.60\.92\.125
RewriteRule (.*) http://eample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "it is not working", can you be more precise? do you have error codes? no redirection at all? breaks all your server? sets the world afire?

Comment: I am trying to improve my seo performance when clicking on IP address it is showing as "Default web site Page"

Comment: I have so many websites on the same IP address it is shared hosting provider where i have hosted my website